# How to create a data.frame with 3 factors?

Tags: r, dataframe

I hope you won't find my question too silly, i did a lot of research but it seems that i can't figure how to solve this really annoying issue.

Well, i have datas for 6 participants (P) in an experiment, with 50 trials (T) per participants and 10 condition (C). So i'd like to create a dataframe in r allowing me to put these datas.
This data.frame should have 3 factors (P, T and C) and so a number of total row of (P*T*C). The difficulty for me is to create this one, since i have the datas for the 6 participant in 6 data.frame of 100 obs(T) by 10 varibles(C).
I'd like first to create the empty dataset with these factors, and then copy the values of the 6 data.set according to the factors P, T and C.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, i'm novice in r.

Thank you.

Comment: This is purely a code question and not a statistical one.  It should be migrated to SO R.

Comment: you might want to check out the stack() function, it gets you part of the way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK; First we create one big dataframe for all participants:

```
result<-rbind(dfrforparticipant1, dfrforparticipant2,...dfrforparticipant6) #you'll have to fill out the proper names of the original data.frames
```

Next, we add a column for the participant ID:

```
numTrials<-50 #although 100 is also mentioned in your question
result$P<-as.factor(rep(1:6, each=numTrials))
```

Finally, we need to go from 'wide' format to 'long' format (I'm assuming your column names holding the results for each condition are called C1, C2 etc. ; I'm also assuming your original data.frames already held a column named T to denote the trial), like this (untested, since you did not provide example data):

```
orgcolnames<-paste("C", 1:10, sep="")
result2<-reshape(result, varying=list(orgcolnames), v.names="val", idvar=c("T","P"), timevar="C", times=seq_along(orgcolnames), direction="long")
```

What you want is now in `result2`.